# Como recorrer dos array en jquery y mostrar una alerta

Tags: jquery

```
<input type="text" class="form-control input-sm"  name="cantidad[]" 
id="cantidad" style="width: 50px" value="<?php echo $row['cantidad']; ?>">

 <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm"  name="cantidad_aprob[]" 
 id="cantidad_aprob" style="width: 50px" value="<?php echo 
 $row['cantidad_aprob']; ?>">
```

**Esta es mi función en `JQuery`**:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  $("#cantidad_aprob").keyup(function(){

  $("input[name='cantidad[]']").each(function(indice, cantidad) {

  $("input[name='cantidad_aprob[]']").each(function(indice, cantidad_aprob) 
 {

   if( $(cantidad_aprob).val() > $(cantidad).val())
   {
     alert("la cantidad aprobada no debe ser mayor a la cantidad pedida")

   |    } 
     });
  });
})
</script>
```

Como recorrer los dos `arrays`, el de `cantidad` y `cantidad aprob` para preguntar si la `cantidad aprob` es mayor a la cantidad dejando claro que los valores de la `cantidad` están ocultos con un `hidden` y solo se digita la `cantidad aprob` en los inputs.

Con este código que tengo solo me toma el valor del primer `input` y en los demás `input` no funciona y yo quiero que en cada input me salga esa alerta por individual, al digitalizar un número mayor en el primer input de la `cantidad aprob` me sale el mensaje de todos los `input` que hay.

**Nota:** Estoy realizando un sistema de pedidos y solo me falta esa validación no soy muy bueno con `JQuery` por eso estoy perdido.

Answer (score 0):

No puedes usar `id` si tienes multiples inputs, necesitas usar clases.  Algo asi:

```js
$(".cantidad_aprob").on("blur", function() {
  var cantidad = parseInt($(this).prev().val());
  if (cantidad < $(this).val()) {
    alert("la cantidad aprobada no debe ser mayor a la cantidad pedida")
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="form-control input-sm"  name="cantidad[]" 
id="cantidad" style="width: 50px" value="60">

 <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm cantidad_aprob"  name="cantidad_aprob[]" 
  style="width: 50px" value="">
  <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm"  name="cantidad[]" 
id="cantidad" style="width: 50px" value="50">

 <input type="text" class="form-control input-sm cantidad_aprob"  name="cantidad_aprob[]" 
  style="width: 50px" value="">
```